# iPhone - Using UIView Animations on touched location

Tags: iphone, uiview, touch, uiviewanimation

I am stumped here as of right now, I wish to enact a UIView Animation on a finger press, by creating a UIView around where the finger is placed. Is this possible?

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pos = [touch locationInView: [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
    NSLog(@"Position of touch: %.3f, %.3f", pos.x, pos.y);
    //CGRect touchFrame = CGRectMake(pos.x, pos.y, 100, 100);
    UIView *box = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(pos.x, pos.y, 100, 100)];
    NSLog(@"%f", box.frame.origin.x);
    [self.view addSubview:box];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:110 forView:box cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [box removeFromSuperview];
    [box release];
}
```

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: It is possible but what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Oops I'm sorry! Getting a little tired here. When this is run, there is no affect applied to the set box area.

Comment: this should be fixed by setting the bounds of the view, instead of its frame like you do. see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its due to u written following line

```
[box removeFromSuperview];
    [box release];
```

This line u have to call after completion of box image animation.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{

    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint pos = [touch locationInView: [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

    UIView *box = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(pos.x, pos.y, 100, 100)];

    [self.view addSubview:box];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:110 forView:box cache:NO];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

[self performSelector:@selector(releaseBoxImge:) withObject:box afterDelay:1.0];

}


-(void)releaseBoxImge:(UIView *)boxImage
{

[boxImage removeFromSuperview];

    [boxImage release];

}
```

Comment: This did not help, although I see where you are going with this. Wouldn't it have to be [[self box] removeFromSuperview]? Since it is created and allocated within TouchesBegan. If I just alloc/initialize it in the header file, can I just do something like
box.frame = CGRectMake(pos.x, pos.y, 100, 100); ?

Comment: sorry i forgetting passing your box image to selector method.Above edited code now definitely will work.

Comment: This is does not create the animation on the UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Like RRB said, do the `removeFromSuperView` after completion of the animation (I'm not sure sure his code would). It should look like this, I think:

```
//initializations of everything here ..
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0                  
 animations:^
 {
   //do animations here
 }
 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
    //do clean up here
 }];
```